# AES improvement the of speed processing by multi threaded task

Tags: multithreading, aes

i implemented AES basic function but it is too slow , how can threading my enable on the AES function to improve the speed parallel process

Answer (score 0):

you can't speed up it by using multiple threads.

Some encryption algorithms use pseudo-random stream of bytes and XOR them with input data.
So you could pre-calculate(predict) parts of such stream in parallel threads and encrypt parts of the same buffer simultaneously.

But each round of encryption in AES algorithm depends on the state of previous rounds so you **can't** speed up it by using multithreading.

Actually my answer can be both true and false depending on what mode do you use but most likely you do not use EBC mode so you can't speed it up.

Comment: what about this "Improving the throughput of the AES algorithm with multicore processors"https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261114554_Improving_the_throughput_of_the_AES_algorithm_with_multicore_processors

Comment: authors are using some mode which is not considered as secure. I advice against using such mode